# TypeError on Apps Script onEdit(event)

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, triggers

I'm a novice user/not an engineer trying Apps Script for the first time. I've copied an Apps Script code that's active in an existing Google Sheet and have been able to get it applied to other Sheets successfully. For some reason, it's not applying in my third doc I'm trying. The Execution log is showing a TypeError for line 6 but it's the same in the other Sheets and it still works in those.

```
function onEdit(event) {
// assumes source data in sheet named "Current Agenda"
// target sheet of move to named "Archived Agenda Notes"
// test column with Answered is col 3 or C
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var s = event.source.getActiveSheet();
var r = event.source.getActiveRange();

if(s.getName() == "Weekly Agenda" && r.getColumn() == 3 && r.getValue() == "Answered") {
var row = r.getRow();
var numColumns = s.getLastColumn();
var targetSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Archived Agenda");
if(targetSheet.getLastRow() == targetSheet.getMaxRows()) {

  targetSheet.insertRowsAfter(targetSheet.getLastRow(), 20); //inserts 20 rows after last used row
}
    var target = targetSheet.getRange(targetSheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1);
s.getRange(row, 1, 1, numColumns).moveTo(target);
s.deleteRow(row);
}
}
```

The use case is different 1:1 docs between myself and individual team members. When I change column C status to Answered, I want the row to move to the Archive tab. The same code is working in other docs, but in this one it's not working. I have line items marked as "Answered" and they are just sitting in the weekly agenda tab.

What's also weird is I've added another similar code in the same project for when the value is "Feedback" to move it to a Feedback tab, and that's working!

Any ideas why "Answered" and the archived agenda move wouldn't be working here?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. One of the core premises of this site workings is that users should search this site before posting a question. Another core premise is that questions about code that throws an error should include the textual error message. Once said that, it's very likely that you have tried to run this code from the script editor rather than letting it respond to the edit event.

Comment: Ok, thank you! The error in the Execution Log is: "TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'source')
onEdit @ Code.gs:6" <-- However, that doesn't seem to be impacting functionality in other docs. I noticed that it appears to be working for new line items, but not existing ones. Is that a common troubleshooting situation with onEdit events?

Comment: Is the onEdit function contained in an Apps Script project bound to a spreadsheet (Google Sheets)? How is the onEdit function being called?

Comment: Did you create installable triggers?

Comment: Yes, it's bound to a spreadsheet. I don't think I created any installable triggers!